# How to set up decorators in Babel 5?

Tags: decorator, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

Decorators in my project do not work. I include this as first line `import 'babel-core/polyfill'` but still have an error

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: .../index.js: Unexpected token
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `{"stage": 0}` to `.babelrc`?

Comment: No, I set up babel-loader via webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

If you really need babel5 instead of babel6 here is documentation for the former

https://github.com/babel/babel.github.io/blob/5.0.0/docs/usage/experimental.md

you can have `.babelrc` in your project root with content:

```
{
    "optional": ["es7.decorators"],
}
```